# Can it be possible "Perpetual Atmospheric Engine"?

Tags: pressure, perpetual-motion

Source: Perpetual Atmospheric Engine-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3t-NkfpFOc

My motivation to believe this idea comes from "Pythagoras Cup (Greedy Cup)", like in this cup, there is no balanced water level and pressure difference. However, I could not be so sure, so I am asking to you.

NOTE: This is not some kind of an infinite perpetual machine or free energy things, we can use gravity and other natural forces to convert energy, so it can be physically logical.

(Pythagoras Cup (Greedy Cup)-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISfIT3B4y6E)

Comment: Not clear. Your question should include any essential information needed to provide an answer. Links can be broken, then your question becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

No. What is depicted appears to be a perpetual motion machine of the first kind. That is to say it violates conservation of energy: the center of mass of the water remains the same, so it is not losing any potential energy, and yet the system appears to do work.

Most likely there is simply a pump hidden somewhere in the system.